# Postgresql and sails js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I am new to sails js and postgresql.

I wanted to make my first record in my database but it doesn't work.

Someone can help me?

Below is my code

NB: in my console there is the "OK" but there is nothing in the database
//config/datastores.js :
default: {
database: 'ticketing',
host: 'localhost',
user: 'root',
password: 'root',
port: 5434,
poolSize: 10,
ssl: false
}

```
//controllers/ConnecterController.js
module.exports = {
connecter: function(req, res){
    var nom = req.param("nom");
    var prenom = req.param("prenom");
    var categorie = req.param("categorie");
    var password = req.param("password");
    //res.view('pages/home', {nom: nom, prenom: prenom, categorie: categorie, password: password});
   Connecter.create(req.allParams(), function connecterCreated(err, connecter){
if(err){
   console.log("Erreur:" + err);
}
else{
   console.log("Ok");
   res.view('pages/home', { nom: nom, prenom: prenom, categorie: categorie, password: password});
   };
  });
 }

};

//models/Connecter.js
module.exports = {

attributes: {

   id: { type: 'number', autoIncrement: true},
   nom: { type: 'string', required: true },
   prenom: { type: 'string', required: true },
   categorie: { type: 'string', required: true },
   password: { type: 'string', required: true },

  },
 };

//config/datastores.js
default:{
   database: 'ticketing',
   host: 'localhost',
   user: 'root',
   password: 'root',
   port: 5434,
   poolSize: 10,
   ssl: false
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the default setup , you are using a basic database that sails provide.
You can read about it here:

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-datastores

To use postgres ,first you have install with NPM the adapter to connect sails with postgres.

```
npm install sails-postgresql
```

Then , in your datastores you have to define your database connection:

```
default: {    
    adapter: 'sails-postgresql',
    url: 'postgresql://username:password@127.0.0.1:5432/databasename'
  },
```

Then you add your model , as you already did.

Bonne chance !